serving file via fastify works on localhost but not on specific ip address (only chrome)
I have set up a fastify server which is supposed to serve files from a redis server.
I have set up the server like so:
const fastify = Fastify({
    logger: {
        transport: {
            target: 'pino-pretty',
            options: {
                translateTime: 'HH:MM:ss Z',
                ignore: 'pid,hostname',
            },
        },
    },
})

fastify.register(cors, { origin: '*' });

fastify.listen({host: "0.0.0.0", port : Number(process.env.EXPRESS_PORT) }, async (err, address) => {
    if (err) {
        fastify.log.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log(`Server running at ${address}`);
    // do some other stuff
});

and then later on there is a get routine like so:
fastify.get('/query_tile/:z/:x/:y', async (request: FastifyRequest<{ Params: BodyType, Querystring: Querystring }>, reply) => {
    const t0 = performance.now();
    const setHeader = () => {
        reply.header('Content-Encoding', 'br');
        reply.header('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
        reply.header('Vary', 'Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
        reply.header('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=tile_${z}_${x}_${y}.mvt`);
        reply.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    }
    // Some other stuff here...
    reply.send(cachedData);

it all works great when I access the server form localhost using http://localhost:3001/..... it downloads the file expected just fine with every browser.
when I access the server via http://192.168.0.123:3001/.... it does download the file when in Firefox, but not in Chrome!?
the error message in Chrome is:

(failed)net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

which does not make any sense in my opinion. Looking at the log there is exactly the same data being sent when looking at cachedData
Soo what's the issue with Chrome here?!

Do you call fastify.register(cors before fastify.get()?
